# Why did a ImageButton go outside the screen in GridLayout?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

My issue: a ImageButton go outside the screen in GridLayout. How do I fix a display issue? What am I doing wrong?

Original picture:

[image: original picture]

Problem picture:

[image: problem picture]

Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLinLyt = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    linearLayout.setLayoutParams(paramsLinLyt);

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(this);
    gridLayout.setOrientation(GridLayout.VERTICAL);

    int rows = 4;
    int cols = 4;
    gridLayout.setRowCount(rows);
    gridLayout.setColumnCount(cols);

    ImageCropProcessor imageCropProcessor = new ImageCropProcessor();
    Bitmap[][] bitmaps = imageCropProcessor.cropImage(getResources(), R.drawable.tiger, rows, cols);

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            GridLayout.Spec buttonRowSpec = GridLayout.spec(i);
            GridLayout.Spec buttonSpecColumn = GridLayout.spec(j);

            ImageButton imagebutton = new ImageButton(this);
            imagebutton.setId(j + 1 + (i * 4));
            imagebutton.setImageBitmap(bitmaps[i][j]);

            gridLayout.addView(imagebutton, new GridLayout.LayoutParams(buttonRowSpec, buttonSpecColumn));
        }
    }
linearLayout.addView(gridLayout);
setContentView(linearLayout);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is too large and doesn't fit on your screen.

The dimensions of a `GridLayout` are determined by it's contents. The content you are trying to show is just too large, so a portion of it is outside the visible screen.

You can try and scale your image so it fits the screen. When doing so, you should preserve the width / height ratio so the image is not altered.

Check out `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Your answer is true. Accept this answer